# What is the current classification of linear motors used for positioning and scanning applications?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, induction-motor, linear

I am doing some research on positioning and scanning systems but I am encountering some problems trying to categorize linear motors. I can't understand what type of linear motors based on induction are available. I tried to categorize into the following table where each cell corresponds to the possibility to choose between one of the element.

```
TYPE            SUB-TYPE       BEARINGS
induction       stepper motor  air bearings
                servo motor    guide bearings

piezoelectric   stepper motor
                squiggle motor
```

For instance, I can have an induction stepper motor with air bearing, or an induction servo motor with air bearings and so on with the other combinations.
I don't understand if the induction linear motor can be subdivided in stepper and servo motor as I did. And this hold true also for thrust-tube motors, that however, I think are not used in positioning and scanning applications. Is there a more extensive and precise categorization of the linear motors available for positioning and scanning applications?

Answer (score 2):

Motors can probably be classified in different ways depending on the reason for classifying them. It appears that you may be attempting to classify motors starting with their fundamental mode of operation.

You seem to be using the term "induction" where it would be more appropriate to use "electromagnetic." An **electromagnetic motor** converts electric current and magnetic fields to mechanical force.

A **piezoelectric motor** is a type of **electrostatic motor**. An electrostatic motor uses an electric field to create a force

**Electromagnetic motors** can use either alternating current of direct current. **Alternating current motors** use rotating magnetic fields. **Direct current motors** have stationary magnetic fields and use a commutator or another form of sliding contact to allow the rotor's magnetic field to remain aligned with the stator field.

**Induction motors** are a type of **AC motor** that has a rotating magnetic field induced in the rotor by the stator field. The stator and rotor field rotate together in synchronism with an angle between them but the rotor speed is not synchronous with the magnetic fields. Induction motors are also called asynchronous motors. Sub-categories of induction motors include **squirrel-cage motors** and **wound-rotor motors**.

**Reluctance motors** are a type of AC motor that has only the rotating magnetic field produced by the stator. The rotor does not have its own magnetic field. The rotor turns synchronously with the stator field under the force of the magnetic field to maintain the path of lowest reluctance.

**Synchronous motors** have magnetic fields that are produced in the rotor by permanent magnets, **permanent-magnet synchronous motors** or by DC current in the rotor **wound-field synchronous motors**. The attraction of that magnetic field to the rotating stator field keeps the rotor turning synchronously with the stator field.

**Brushless DC motors** are similar to synchronous motors. They have rotating magnetic fields that are produced by electronic control schemes either built into the motor or in an external control unit.

**Stepper motors** are motors that rotate in incremental steps rather than in a steady motion. They are not exactly part of the above classification system. Stepper action can be implemented in reluctance and synchronous types of motors. Induction motors are not good candidates for use as stepper motors.

**Servo motors** are also not part of the above classification system. They are used for precise position control. They generally use motion and position feedback in implementing a control scheme. Most of the above motor types can be used as servo motors.

Many of the above types of motors can be constructed as **Linear Motors**.

Selection of the motor type for use as servo motors, linear motors, position control, scanning etc. Depends on the order of magnitude of power involved. Motors have been constructed in power levels from microwatts to megawatts.

Bearings, motor enclosure types, mounting provisions, cooling provisions and other construction details are not covered by the above classification system. Those are design details that are applicable to most types of motors.

Comment: +1 for the excellent answer, but for instance, we can find also linear stepper motor https://www.h2wtech.com/category/linear-stepper-stages#productInfo1 so your definition is not completely correct

Comment: @GM, the answer does not preclude the existance of linsear stepper motors.  This is an excellent review, more than sufficient to allow anyone to understand any motor not on the list by reading.  In fact, this answer is making me favorite a question I was tempted to close as too general.

Comment: @GM, T\the classification that I presented is based on the basic techniques used to convert electrical energy to mechanical energy. That is generally how motors are presented in the marketplace. Stepper motors are a different configuration of some of those basic techniques. I believe that induction motors are precluded from use as stepper motors even though they were perhaps the first to be used as linear motors and have been used in positioning applications.

Comment: @ScottSeidman what I am saying is that "Stepper motors are motors that rotate in incremental steps" is not correct because they do not necessarily rotate.

Comment: @GM, all of the descriptions that I provided are based on rotating motors. They dominate the study, research, development and industry of electric motors. Linear motors are generally treated as an adaptation of rotary motors. That is probably why you are having difficulty finding the information that you need.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good start and each combination has a useful application in industry for both Linear AND rotary motion control with position feedback and current or energy control with time to control motion of mass. the air bearings only affect friction due to gravity.

Examples:

- power meter with rotating disc is on a magnetic spindle rotary vertical air bearing to prevent drag with low induced torque from metal eddy currents and torque.
- Maglev train uses sequential magnets to step and accelerate linear motion by V/F control and friction free air bearing.
- HDD Servo writer  uses a air bearing rotary induction motor to eliminate wobble due to bearing friction on large HDD’s . Now small HDD’s are ferro-fluidic spindles to bind the grease from contaminating the HDA, head disk Assy, and the embedded inter-sector gaps are written between tracks to give a relative dibits for position error signal, PES, while Rotary Head motor uses rare earth magnet and moving rectangular voice coil on similar clean bearings to last > 100 million seeks
- linear stepper is actually rotary motor with gear/belt conversion to linear motion with gear ratio as diameter but std packed grease bearings.
- original fastest 14 and 5.25” HDD’s used much bigger linear fixed magnet moving coils and relied on dedicated surface for Servo PES.
- induction motors accelerate with current DC to AC or AC and use current feedback then integrate for v or differentiate Position to control velocity then use Position sensors for feedback such as differential Quadrature encoders with a home sensor .
- Piezo types use charge energy to move a certain distance by combining Voltage and C to load C such as those Inkjet printers or microMEM pumps or perhaps nano pump technology. I.e. dump then short accelerates and stops with known load.

Many more examples but gotta get back to fixing gearbox in hedge trimmer.

Steppers are incremental and not absolute, so some reference sensor is needed for home and/or GPS .  E.g. Floppy drives used an optical home sensor for Track 0

Comment: I don't think that a linear stepper motor is actually a rotatory with gear/belt conversion https://www.linearmotiontips.com/faq-what-are-linear-stepper-motors/#:~:text=In%20a%20linear%20stepper%20motor%2C%20the%20base%2C%20or%20platen%2C,windings%2C%20and%20a%20permanent%20magnet.&text=The%20step%20angle%20can%20be,control%20of%20the%20motor's%20rotation.

Comment: Yes those are True linear, but they still call floppy drives with linear steppers or at least they did in the 70's, besides how far can you drive in one direction with those? (lol)

Comment: you can drive a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADweCqkUWHk I don't understand why positioning systems motor are never well described. I can't find any good positioning system and motors classification

Comment: From the user perspective the rotary motor motion is linear